# How to change the chapter representation

Tags: sectioning, numbering, chapters

I would like to replace the writing produced by the creation of any chapter such as "Chapter 3" with one at my pleasure that still shows the chapter number such as "Story 3"

[image]

[image]

I have tried using this package without success:

```
\usepackage{fmtcount}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Numberstring{chapter}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command `\chaptername` from the `titlesec` package can be used for that. As an example, the third chapter
[image]
is produced with the following code.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{Story}
\begin{document}
\chapter{}
\chapter{}
\chapter{Case Study}
\end{document}
```